# Pathmodel fully saturated vs trimming insignificant path

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, path-model

I am using a pathmodel to analyze a multiple mediation. I have three exogenous variables ($x_1,x_2,x_3$) and two mediator endogenous variables ($m_1,m_2$) and one final endogenous variable that is the criteria / dependent variable ($y$).

Since this has not been tested previously there is no theoretical reasoning for constraints. So it is a fully saturated model (with $df = 0$). I am fairly unexperienced when it comes to SEM / Pathmodel, however I know that in a saturated model, the fit statistics are perfect and are probably not supposed to be reported. My first question would be, is ok to report a fully saturated model and just interpret the weights of the paths (and dont even bother to report fit statistics)?

A follow up questions stems from a tipp I recently read on a forum. It is, that you could successively constrain non-significant paths from your model, i.e. delete them from the lavaan model specification. As with this, you increase the degrees of freedom and the model fit statistics become interpretable. However I am not sure if this is a good practice?
As it seem arbitrary to me to just cut insignificant paths from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no theoretical model to support your analysis, reporting the saturated model without fit statistics seems the best option. Removing non-significant results will gives you artificially good fit statistics, just because you developed the model in a statistics fashion (removing non significant path) rather than a theoretical one (justified conceptually).